# How to differentiate the input from hand held scanner/ gun scanner and from keyboard in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode-scanner, jquery-events

We have the functionality of auto complete for input fields but I wanted to prevent the functionality of auto complete when user use gun scanner

Comment: You can set value from gun scanner directly to `value` attribute of the input element and your auto-complete functionality should only work on `onChange` or `onKeyPress`.

Comment: @AvtarNanrey The scanner is most likely emulating a keyboard and therefore there is no code which Sam can modify to avoid the onChange or onKeyPress events.

Answer (score 1):

The scanner probably just sends keystrokes to the input. In that case there is no programmatic way to know that a scanner was used. However, what you can do is detect the speed the keys were sent. Above some threshold you know that its is probably not a human typing and you can disable auto complete.

Answer (score 1):

Many keyboard input barcode scanners have the ability to customize prefix/suffix codes that are appended to the front and back to identify barcode data input.

They can be customized by reading the settings barcode.

For example, if you can turn on/off the auto-completion of the input field programmatically, turn off auto-completion when you receive the key code indicating the start of data from the scanner in the KeyDown event, and when you receive the key code indicating the end of data from the scanner, turn on auto-completion.